# Needing some Huffman assistance

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to implement a compression/decompression algorithm in Java, and this is my current progress: [full source code](http://pastebin.com/fqY0bEyP).

Just have two things I am not entirely sure on how to fix:

1. When I compress files its working for everything except files with small number of bytes. A friend told me the problem is that when we compress files, we will need the tree, and have to store it in the file itself, thus making the compressed file bigger due to the tree. Any pointers as to how to fix that?
2. Not sure how to implement decompression at all.

Comment: For (1), think Pidgeonhole Principles. If you have 256 possible one byte files, they have to be placed in 256 different 'compressed' results. Obviously to compress some, others will have to be made larger. The point of compression algorithms is that they compress files that are high in information and thus patterns, and as a consequence random noise files will be made larger.

Comment: here are some [pointers](http://xkcd.com/138/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1 can not be solved. For example, if you have a file with only 3 different bytes and you do a huffman compression you create a tree like this: http://huffman.ooz.ie/?text=asd

So, the tree from the compressed file is automatically bigger than your complete old file, but if you would do any other thing, it would not be a huffman compression anymore. Same for all files with very many different bytes. **Principally: More equal bytes in a file will bring a better result after compression**

Second thing is very generally, but for some help look at this code: https://github.com/nayuki/Huffman-Coding/blob/master/src/nayuki/huffmancoding/HuffmanDecompress.java

Comment: I might add that if you use _lossless compression_, you cannot always win ! What you win in some cases must be lost in other cases ;)

Answer (score 1):

The tree can be stored in a quite compact way.

I did it once - basically I traversed the tree in a LR pattern. So at node N, if the left branch is a leaf then write a `1` followed by the symbol this leaf encodes, otherwise just write a `0` and descend into that node.

Then do the same for the right branch - if it is a leaf write `1` then symbol, if it is a node write `0` and descend into that node.

This tree http://huffman.ooz.ie/?text=asd (thanks to Bernhard!) could be written as `1[D]01[A]1[S]` which is 28bits or 4 bytes total (eg. replace [D] with `01000100`).

Decoding the table is done in the reverse manner. I don't have time to write the code, but it does work, and I believe it must be close to the most compact encoding for the tree (not that I have any evidence of that).